# Sencha compare before edit value and edited value in Row editing

Tags: extjs

I need to compare the value before edit and updated value with row editor update.and I need to send json string to backend with only edited values. Please let me know the best methodology.

Thank you.

Comment: Is there a service implemented at the backend which you can use for sending changes or are you asking for a greenfield solution?

Answer (score 2):

You attach to the edit event of the grid and collect all values which changes

```
var changes = [];

grid.on('edit', function(editor, context) {
    var originalValue = context.value;
    var newValue = record.get(context.field);
    if ( originalValue !== newValue ) {
        changes.push(context);
    }
});
```